# Jquery .click() not working on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, canvas, input

I have a mobile web app where the user clicks on an empty canvas element to upload a photo.
The way I am doing this is with an input type="file" element and when the user clicks the empty canvas (if no image is already loaded) JavaScript simulates a 'click' on the hidden input type file element which pops up the file select dialogue.

It is working everywhere but android, any ideas?

```
$("#canvas").click(function() {
    if (!imageLoaded) {
        $('#imageLoader').click();  // <-- this is the issue here
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more code?

Comment: Maybe something is overlapping the image that you can't see?

Comment: Can you please post the code that is working in a jsFiddle and provide us the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code.

```
$(document).on("mousedown touchstart","#canvas" ,function() {
        if (!imageLoaded) {
            $('#imageLoader').trigger('click');  // <-- this is the issue here
        }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will want to trigger the click - http://jsfiddle.net/6AmLZ/1/

```
$('#imageLoader').click(function() {
    console.log('image loader has been clicked');
});
$("#canvas").click(function() {
    $('#imageLoader').trigger('click');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

While what you're doing will trigger the second click I have found the Android platform wanting more sometimes. I would also try, as others have suggested, that nothing is overlaying the canvas on the Android platform and it is using your CSS as you would expect it to.